# PHP: вывод предупреждения

Tags: php

Здравствуйте, товарищи!

Есть код, который участвует в загрузке картинок на сервер. Всё бы хорошо, но если выводится сообщение об ошибке (не тот тип файла, если попробовать залить скрипт или что либо отличное от картинки), то выводится предупреждение: `Warning: finfo_file(): Empty filename or path in ...php on line 82`

Это конечно ничего, мы знаем, что пусто, а сообщения об ошибках можно потом отключить, но это ведь как-то не правильно, что выводится в принципе. Я вот думаю, можно ли подставлять что-то по-умолчанию, чтобы оно не ругалось? Что-то вроде: `finfo_file() = null` или как-то по-иному…

Вот код:

```
if (isset($_FILES['file'])) {
    $fileTmpName = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    $fileInfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
    $mime = (string) finfo_file($fileInfo, $fileTmpName);
    if (strpos($mime, 'image') === false) {
        $message = 'Возможна загрузка только изображений!';
    } else {
        $image = getimagesize($fileTmpName);
        $extension = image_type_to_extension($image[2]);
        $path = 'Public/img/uploads/' . uniqid() . $extension;
        move_uploaded_file($fileTmpName, $path);
        $id = $this->model->fileUpload($path);
        $message = 'Файл загружен!';
    }
}
```

Comment: а чем не устраивает `if (!$fileInfo) {
    $message = "Открытие базы данных fileinfo не удалось";
    exit();
}`  ?

Comment: А так ведь, мне нужно просто чтобы выводилось «Грузите только картинки», если пытаются что-то иное залить :) А если exit(), то отваливается макет)) Или можно просто проверять if (!$fileInfo) и тогда не будет ругаться?

Comment: А можно дурацкий вопрос? Почему работа идёт с переменной $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], а на существование проверяется $_FILES['file']?

Answer (score 0):

Проще получить тип из массива данных о файле.

```
if (
    isset($_FILES['file'])
    && strpos($_FILES['file']['type'], 'image') !== false
) {
    echo "type: image";
}
```

Пример может содержать потенциальною уязвимость.

Как уточнил [Ипатьев](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/179379/%D0%98%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D0%B5%D0%B2)

> Никогда нельзя доверять информации, пришедшей из браузера

Я соглашусь с данным утверждением. Хоть и упустил его изначально.

---

С помощью `isset` вы определяете установленна переменная `$_FILES`. При входе на страницу (**GET** запросе) эта проверка работает. Но, если вы отправите форму без файла, переменная `$_FILES` будет создана, но с пустыми значениями.
[Документация](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php#2), предпоследний абзац второго примера.

```
array(1) {
  ["file"]=>
  array(5) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["type"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["tmp_name"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["error"]=>
    int(4)
    ["size"]=>
    int(0)
  }
}
```

Поэтому, перед тем как считывать файл нужно проверить, что файл был отправлен. Это можно сделать с помощью поля `error` или проверить содержит ли массив данные об имени или временном пути файла.

```
if (isset($_FILES['file']) && $_FILES['file']['error'] === UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
    $finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
    $mime = finfo_file($finfo, $_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);

    if (strpos($mime, 'image') !== false) {
        // Save file
    } else {
        // error
    }
}
```

Comment: А как это применить в моём коде? Не соображу, к сожалению…

Comment: Никогда нельзя доверять информации, пришедшей из браузера

Comment: @Ипатьев, Спасибо. Упустил этот момент.

Comment: Лучше наверно проверить что файл корректно загружен, это статус `UPLOAD_ERR_OK` Потому как помимо `UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE` есть и другие ошибки загрузки.